# how can i draw a gaussian curve on datas which obey gaussian distribution by R language?

Tags: r, gaussian

I have some datas which looks like obeying gausssian distribution. So i use

`my.glm<- glm(b1~a1,family=Gaussian)`

and then use command

`summary(my.glm)`.

The results are:

```
Call:
glm(formula = b1 ~ a1, family = gaussian)

Deviance Residuals: 
      Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max  
-0.067556  -0.029598   0.002121   0.030980   0.044499  

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)  0.433697   0.018629   23.28 1.36e-12 ***
a1          -0.027146   0.001927  -14.09 1.16e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 0.001262014)

Null deviance: 0.268224  on 15  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 0.017668  on 14  degrees of freedom
AIC: -57.531

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2
```

I think they fit well. But how can i draw a gaussian curve on these datas?

Comment: Do you really understand what family=Gaussian means? It's got nothing to do with the distribution of your data, but everything to do with the relationship between your variables. Its saying "a1 is a linear function of b1 *with uncorrelated Gaussian noise*". Now ask your question again.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the intercept has a normal distribution, you can plot its distribution like this:

```
x <- seq(0.3,0.6,by =0.001)
plot(x, dnorm(x, 0.433697, 0.018629), type = 'l')
```

and you might want to add your data:

```
rug(b1)
```

since you didn't supply data, we can make some up (with some transforms to match stats in the example):

```
set.seed(0)
b <- rnorm(15)
b1 <- ((b - mean(b))/sd(b)  * 0.018629) + 0.433697
rug(b1)
```

you could also overlay a kernel density estimate of the data

```
lines(density(b1), col = 'red')
```

Giving the following plot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simple:  `?dnorm`

Use dnorm to create a gaussian curve of desired mean and s.d.  without tying yourself to any numerically fitted function. This is a simple, and good, way to show how your data 'fits' to a theoretical curve.  Not the same thing as plotting the fitted data and trying to figure out "how close" to a gaussian it is.

Comment: Maybe I'm getting crotchety in my declining years, but whazzup w/ the downvote?  The guy did ask how to draw a gaussian, not how to fit one.